# TYPO3: how to create a validator for field values when record is stored in the DB

Tags: annotations, typo3, customvalidator

I am looking for a way to validate a property of my Domain Model each time the record is stored in the database.

I had a look to the documentation on "Validation" and also on "Annotation", but was not able to get it working.

My model has a property defined:

```
    /**
     * vcFilename
     *
     * @var string
     * @Validate("Averlon\AvVcard\Domain\Validator\VcFilenameValidator")
     */
    protected string $vcFilename = '';
```

I have created a Validator which looks like this (at the moment):

```
class VcFilenameValidator extends AbstractValidator
{
    protected function isValid(mixed $value): void
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        echo '$value' . '<br>';
        var_dump($value);
        echo '</pre>';
        echo '<br>';

        die();
    }
```

But when storing a record in a folder in my BE nothing dies!

Normally, when I do this for testing purpose in other areas I get the output from var_dump in my BE.

What could be wrong?

Comment: As far as I know, Extbase validators are only taken into account when used in frontend. In backend you have to use TCA. What do you want to validate, please give an example.

Comment: @Chris; the field I want to validate is a filename. I just want to check if the extension is correct. Something like if (!str_ends_with($vCardRecord['vc_filename'], '.vcf')). So nothing complicated.
But probably, once it works in general, I will find something more to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extbase validators are not meant for the TYPO3 backend but only for the frontend. If you want to validate the backend input you have two options:

1. The first one is to extend the 'eval' configuration using https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/11.5/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Input/Properties/Eval.html#custom-eval-rules
2. There are many hooks in the datahandler which is used to store the records in the backend. Here you could validate the input before or after saving https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/66e6210e079c54f52253bb53c805673acefe6abc/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/DataHandling/DataHandler.php#L1124

Comment: I will look into eval!
I already have some working hook but I need to look into it in more detail how I can return error messages to be shown in BE form.

P.S.: nowhere in the docu was mentioned, that Validators are for FE and not for BE. At least I did not recognize any hint. An I have read this several times.

Comment: I had a typo in the namespace parameters in ext_localconf.php. Now I get the first results. Still not what I want to achieve but a start!
Thanks for help.